# How to display specific gif based on key press event using Pyglet?

Tags: python, gif, keypress, keyevent, pyglet

Code I got so far

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
 
 

animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('/home/arctic/Downloads/work/gif/ErrorToSurprised.gif')

animSprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

w = animSprite.width
h = animSprite.height
 
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=w, height=h, resizable=True)
 
 
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.A:
        animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('image1.gif')
 
    elif symbol == key.B:
        animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('image2.gif')
 
    elif symbol == key.ENTER:
        print("Enter Key Was Pressed")
 
 
 
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
 
 
 
pyglet.app.run()
```

This yields an error, i dont think im loading in the gif correctly under elif symbol==key. This function display a window default gif. Then listening to a key press, depending on the key display a certain gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You're not drawing anything to the screen in `on_draw`, so nothing will appear. You need to add `animSprite.draw()`.
2. You are correct that your method of changing the sprite animations is wrong. Currently, you are just loading an animation into a local `animation` variable and doing nothing with it. You have to change the `animSprite.image` property to a new animation.

Here is a version of your code with both these changes.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

initial_animation = pyglet.image.load_animation(
    "/home/arctic/Downloads/work/gif/ErrorToSurprised.gif"
)
animation_1 = pyglet.image.load_animation("image1.gif")
animation_2 = pyglet.image.load_animation("image2.gif")

animSprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(initial_animation)

w = animSprite.width
h = animSprite.height

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=w, height=h, resizable=True)


@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.A:
        animSprite.image = animation_1

    elif symbol == key.B:
        animSprite.image = animation_2

    elif symbol == key.ENTER:
        print("Enter Key Was Pressed")


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    animSprite.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```